# How i can use pg_restore command to restore a dump residing on a github repo?

Tags: postgresql, pg-restore

I used pg_restore but it does not work:

```
pg_restore -d postgres < https://github.com/someuser/somerepo/blob/somebranch/dump.sql
```

Is this possible with pg_restore?

Comment: Umm - download the file and restore it?

Comment: yup, it's obvious but this is not what I want.

Comment: You either need to move the data to where you run the pg_restore command or run the pg_restore command on the machine where the data is. If you don't have network access (and any required permissions for the github repo) then  this just can't work, can it? Presumably you were trying to download the file with the invalid shell redirect, no?